# Identifier whose declaration cannot be found. TRISbits

Tags: microcontroller, pic, embedded, c, programming

Currently trying to program a PIC32MZ2048EFM144.

I'm new to PIC programming, and I'm currently attempting to set pins J7, 3, and K7 as outputs and set them to a high state. However, I'm encountering an error that says, 'Identifier whose declaration cannot be found.' I'm quite perplexed by this issue since MPLab provides suggestions related to the ports, and the xc.h file doesn't seem to contain any errors.

I've attached some screenshots and included references to the board I'm using. I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance to help me understand what might be causing this problem.

Thank you in advance for your help

[image]

[image]

```c
/*
 * File:   Main.c
 * Author: seanj
 *
 * Created on 01 November 2023, 12:24
 */



//#include "sam.h"

#include <xc.h>

int main(void) {
    /* Replace with your application code */
    
    TRISKbits.TRISK7=0;
    
    LATKbits.LATK7=1;
    LATJbits.LATJ7=1;
    LATJbits.LATJ3=1;
    
    while (1) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Screen shots of text are not useful. Please paste the actual text into your question, formatting as "code" where appropriate.

Comment: did you try to build the project?

Comment: Yes, but it doesnt seem to work when i make the program to the board. it BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 956ms). Identifier whose declaration cannot be found still seems to come tho

Comment: If you have  BUILD SUCCESSFUL you do not have to worry about it. And sometimes helps you add a space bare at the beginning of TRISKbits.TRISK7= 0.

Comment: "If you have BUILD SUCCESSFUL you do not have to worry about it." That's horrible advise if warnings are present. The MPLAB flavoured compilers in particular may default to some C90 mode with implicit int, which can in turn lead to very strange and subtle bugs. Make sure there are no warnings. As for how to solve that, look up which item specifically it can't find.